# Vnc Viewer does not connecting but Windows Remote Desktop works

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I just purchased a VPS and configured a remote desktop, it works fine with Windows Remote Desktop. but it can't be connected with VNC viewer.

I assumed maybe RDs using different ports so executed `netstat -tulpn | grep xrdp` in the server and tried `ip:3389`, but didn't work again.
The server is running on "CentOS release 6.5 (Final)"

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      696/xrdp-sesman
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      692/xrdp
```

Comment: Umm, as far as I can tell from what you've posted, the remote server **is** running an RDP listener and **isn't** running a VNC listener.  They are different procotols; the ability to connect to one using the appropriate tool doesn't imply the ability to connect to the other using the tool appropriate to that.  Do you have any reason to think you *should* be able to connect via VNC?  What does `netstat -an|grep 5900` give you?  (Edit any answer to that last into your question, please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC and RDP use different protocols, so you can't connect to an RDP server with a VNC client.
`xrdp` is a RDP server that manages a VNC server.  In principle you could connect to that VNC server
with a VNC client, but that probably isn't what you want.

Use an RDP client instead.  You don't mention the OS you need it for; on Linux, I've been using [grdesktop](http://www.nongnu.org/grdesktop/shots.html), [Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/screenshots.shtml), [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) and a front-end for it, [gnome-rdp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnome-rdp/).

I've found `grdesktop` too limited in the features it supports and the settings it can save. I'm using Remmina now, and `gnome-rdp` with a [simple wrapper around `rdesktop` that will automatically share drives](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/bin/rdesktop).